# Вызов функций из своей библиотеки в чужом адресном пространстве

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте, коллеги. Задача такая:

Есть моя либа, подгруженная в чужое адресное пространство чужого приложения.
Есть моё приложение с кнопками.
Как можно вызвать функции из моей либы, находящейся в чужом адресном пространстве? И ещё желательно получать от этой либы `result`.
Одним из вариантов вижу использование функции `CreateRemoteThread`. Но опыта использования не имею и информации в интернете крупицы.
Пожалуйста, помогите. С уважением.

Comment: Есть вариант пристроится отладчиком, а после этого сразу много становится доступным.
Но если либа Ваша, можно ли ее доделать/переписать? или ее трогать уже нельзя?

Comment: Если это вообще возможно, то не важно, своя или "чужая" библиотека. Видимо важны права доступа к контексту чужого процесса.

Comment: Библиотека моя, можно дописать. Присматриваюсь к Файл-маппингу, просто опыта нет, приходится очень-очень много читать, учиться :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть очень много различных способов [межпроцессорного взаимодействия](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5).
Я думаю, что для Вашей задачи подойдут сокеты. Самые обычные сокеты. Библиотека создает себе тред, в котором создает серверный сокет и слушает на локалхосте. Так как библиотека находится в чужом адресном пространстве, она может делать в нем многое, что не позволено так просто Вашему приложению.

Тут нужно подумать только о двух ситуациях - когда включать сервер (например при собственно загрузке библиотеки или после вызова определенной функции) и что делать, если Вашу библиотеку использует два и более приложения. Тут наверное красивым решеним будет создавать не tcp сокет, а udp и все клиентские приложения смогут также обмениваться данными. Но с другой стороны, никто не мешает Вашему приложению стать сервером, а библиотека время от времени пытается подключиться.

Comment: Если это решение задачи (ответ принят), то не ясно **причем здесь библиотека в чужом адресном пространстве** ?